# Spring parent project owns bean - can child access it?

Tags: java, spring, singleton, javabeans

If I create a bean class in some parent project, and I want to inject it into the child project into some class, how can I avoid the circular reference to it?  Since the bean is created in the parent, can the child use it?

I think my only solution might be to move this bean into some common library that both projects use.  So I'm asking in case I can learn some new trickery here...

Note- I can't pass the bean as an argument to child - I need to hide its use from an api standpoint.

Comment: Yes, a library is crying to be born.

Comment: An intermediate Bean is the only solution that I know given your requirements